# Authorization failure (no authenticated user) - .htaccess error, Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server

I'm running Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server and I'm trying to protect one of the directories `'myFolder'` which is located at `/var/www/html/myFolder`

I made the following edits in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf file`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/html/myFolder>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I created `.htaccess` in `/var/www/myFolder` with the following contents

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/myFolder/.htpasswd
AuthName "Authorization Required"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Also created htpasswd by

```
htpasswd -c /var/www/html/myFolder/.htpasswd admin
```

which then prompts for password.

I then try to access the file on the browser www.mydoman.com/myFolder/hello.html  and it prompts for username and password. However, the authentication does not go through.

Here is the error from the error.log file

[authz_core:error] [pid 30042] [client xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:53348] AH01629: authorization failure (no authenticated user): /myFolder/hello.html

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 18):

A loaded mod-shib2 can cause this problem. According to [this bug comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shibboleth-sp2/+bug/1358284/comments/9), setting `ShibCompatValidUser On` solves it.

> Require valid-user does also work with mod_shib enabled. According to https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPApacheConfig this is only necessary for shib versions 2.5.2 and above. Note that ShibCompatValidUser is a server / virtual host option.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot.